# Using Buildr within Docpad

Tags: docpad

I'm using [DocPad](https://github.com/bevry/docpad) to build my website, and in the docs it's saying that we can use an helper called `buildr` to bundle, compress files.

Is it possible to integrate `buildr` execution within the command `docpad generate`  or `docpad run`?

Also does it needs it own config file `buildr.coffee` or it's possible to write the configs inside the `docpad.config` plugin section?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it would be more or less the same as [this gist for grunt](https://gist.github.com/3898915) except with the grunt stuff changed to buildr.

Comment: That would be it. Docs for buildr are here https://github.com/balupton/buildr.npm.